# WebMethod having array as a parameter

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I want to write a web method having its one argument as an Array/List.
The code builds successfully but on browser to test it shows following message.
**The test form is only available for methods with primitive types as parameters.**

```
  [WebMethod]
    public string Concat(params string[] arr,int a,int b)
    {
        string result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            result += arr[i];
        }
int c=a+b;
        return result+'_'+c.Tostring();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

string[] it's not a primitive type, as String, o a Integer are.

Maybe you can try SoapUI (http://www.soapui.org).

Or you can place it into a test ASPx page, as a static method, and try it so, vía JS:

```
function test() {
   PageMethods.Concat(array_values,integer1,integer2);
}

function test_callback(result){
  alert(result);
}
```